# What are the advantages of taking "Sculptor of Flesh" eldritch invocation over taking Polymorph as a spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock, eldritch-invocations

I think I misunderstand how the eldritch invocations that grant spells "using a warlock spell slot".

> Sculptor of Flesh Prerequisite: 7th level
>
> You can cast Polymorph once using a Warlock spell slot. You can’t do
>   so again until you finish a Long Rest.

Looking at the Warlock spell list, you are also able to take Polymorph as a spell at 7th level. If I took Polymorph as a spell, couldn't I cast it using pact slots every short rest? What is the point of using this as one of my eldritch invocations?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Polymorph is not, in fact, on the warlock spell list. The only way a single-class warlock can get access to polymorph by themselves is through the invocation.

Comment: Ah, this is correct, I guess I overlooked this fact in my answer

Comment: Me too... Warlock and Wizard were right next to each other, and I misread it.